# Accessing String Values in Pandas DataFrame Efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I need to edit some text string's in a Pandas DataFrame, but 
accessing the strings in an efficient manner proving difficult.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['New York', 'New York (N))', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Texas (S))', 'Texas' ], columns = ['State'], index = [0,1,2, 0, 1, 2])

df2 = df.groupby((df.index==0).cumsum())

df2.get_group(1).values
```

This last line returns a numpy array of arrays. What I want to be able to do is process the text strings, in each group, for example stripping the (N) or (S) if present, and then comparing the resulting strings, in that group, to ensure they are all the same. Different string processing will be required for each group and will often be more complex than simple stripping of letters. What is the best way to do this? Having to use an expression like the below to access each string seems too cumbersome?

```
  df7.get_group(1).values[1][0]
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly do you want ? Your question is quite unclear to me. Do you ""just"" wish to strip the ending `(N))` and `(S))` ?

Comment: Sorry it was unclear. I do want to strip the (N) and (S) I then want to compare the strings in the group to ensure they are the same. This is just for the toy example though in the real problem more complex string processing will be required, so I really want to be able to access/process all the string's in a group at the same time in an efficient manner.

Comment: Have you try using "df.loc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['New York', 'New York (N))', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Texas (S))', 'Texas' ], columns = ['State'], index = [0,1,2, 0, 1, 2])
df2 = df.groupby((df.index==0).cumsum())

df2.get_group(1).State.str.rstrip('(S|N))').str.rstrip().values
```

Output (Valid for New York and Texas):

```
array(['New York', 'New York', 'New York'], dtype=object)
```

You can verify that all the Series elements are the same using:

```
df2.get_group(1).nunique().State == 1
```

PS: The question structure is very difficult to comprehend, please invest more time in making questions concise and to the point.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is 99% there. I have a couple of cases though where the letter in the brackets is the same as the last letter of the state, so  df = pd.DataFrame(['New York', 'New York (k))', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Texas (s))', 'Texas' ], columns = ['State'], index = [0,1,2, 0, 1, 2]). When you apply the solution above it gives array(['New Yor', 'New York', 'New Yor'], dtype=object) i.e. is there a way to ensure it only removes the characters in the brackets?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['New York', 'New York (N))', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Texas (S))', 'Texas' ], columns = ['State'], index = [0,1,2, 0, 1, 2])

N_states = df['State'].str.contains('(N)', regex=False)
df.loc[N_states==True]
```

This works to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [boolean mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking) to filter in which values to change, and then apply the change I want. Here, I chose to use [`Series.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) accessor.

I basically say, `I want to change the values of this column, on these specific rows, by doing a slice.`

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame(['New York', 'New York (k))', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Texas (z))', 'Texas' ], columns = ['State'], index = [0,1,2, 0, 1, 2])

    mask = ~df['State'].str.endswith('))')
    df['State'] = df['State'].where(mask, df['State'].str.slice(stop= -5))

    print(df)
    #       State
    # 0  New York
    # 1  New York
    # 2  New York
    # 0     Texas
    # 1     Texas
    # 2     Texas
```